# How to get string from xml in COM

Tags: c++, com

I have one array like this:

```
static WCHAR FilesToShow[][100] = { { L"start.cmd" },{ L"image.xml" }, { L"xyz" }};
```

as you see that there is "xyz" which I have to replace with some unique name. For this I have to read image.xml file.

Please can you tell me how can I do this.

I wrote a method like this:

```
PRIVATE WCHAR GetSystemName(WCHAR *pName)

{
    WCHAR line;

    wfstream in("image.xml");
    WCHAR tmp; 

    bool begin_tag = false;
    while (getline(in,line))
    {
        // strip whitespaces from the beginning
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            if (line[i] == ' ' && tmp.size() == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                tmp += line[i];
            }
        }        

        if (wcswcs(tmp,"<SystemPath>") != NULL)
        {    
           ???????? how to get "vikash" from here <SystemPath>C:\Users\rs_user\Documents\RobotStudio\Systems\vikash</SystemPath>
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }

    return tmp;
}
```

I'm getting exception for wfstream, getline and line.length() method. 
I have included fstream.h header file but I think It's not supported in COM.

Please help me how to solve this issue without parsing xml file.

Comment: In above question I have replace "xyz" from array with vikash or any dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml-file is simple enough so that there is only a single tag with given name, you could do it like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::wstring get_value(std::wistream & in, std::wstring const & tagname)
{
  std::wstring text = std::wstring(std::istreambuf_iterator<std::wstring::value_type>(in),
                                   std::istreambuf_iterator<std::wstring::value_type>());

  std::wstring start_tag = L"<" + tagname + L">";
  std::wstring end_tag = L"</" + tagname + L">";

  std::wstring::size_type start = text.find(start_tag);
  if (start == std::wstring::npos)
  {
    throw 123;
  }
  start += start_tag.length();

  std::wstring::size_type end = text.find(end_tag);
  if (end == std::wstring::npos)
  {
    throw 123;
  }
  return text.substr(start, end - start);
}

std::wstring get_substr_after(std::wstring const & str, wchar_t delim)
{
  std::wstring::size_type pos = str.rfind(delim);
  if (pos == std::wstring::npos)
  {
    throw 123;
  }
  return str.substr(pos + 1);
}


void stackoverflow()
{
  std::wstring text(L"<foo>\n<bar>abc/def/ghi</bar>\n<baz>123/456/789</baz>\n</foo>\n");
  std::wistringstream wiss(text);

  std::wcout << text << std::endl;
  std::wcout << get_substr_after(get_value(wiss, std::wstring(L"bar")), L'/') << std::endl;

}
```

The output of this program is:

```
<foo>
<bar>abc/def/ghi</bar>
<baz>123/456/789</baz>
</foo>

ghi
```

I hope that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

you have several issues here.

1. what you are getting are compiler errors and not exceptions
2. the header file to include is 'fstream' not 'fstream.h'.
3. make sure you have a line saying `using namespace std;`
4. You are declaring `line` as a variable of type `WCHAR`, so it is a single wide character, which surely is not a `wstring` object. Therefore `line.length()` is incorrect.
5. Why are you mixing C (`wcswcs()`) and C++ (STL) ? maybe you should re-design your function signature.

However, try the below function.  I have modified the signature to return a pointer to `WCHAR`, and place the requested string in the buffer space provided by pName.  I added a check to verify that the buffer is large enough to fit the name and the terminating NULL character.

```
WCHAR* GetSystemName(WCHAR *pName, size_t buflen)
{
    wstring line;
    wifstream in("image.xml");
    WCHAR* tmp = NULL;

    while (getline(in,line))
    {
        // strip whitespaces from the beginning
        size_t beg_non_whitespace = line.find_first_not_of(L" \t");
        if (beg_non_whitespace != wstring::npos)
        {
            line = line.substr( beg_non_whitespace );
        }

        size_t beg_system_path = line.find( L"<SystemPath>" );
        if ( beg_system_path != wstring::npos )
        {    
            // strip the tags (assuming closing tag is present)
            size_t beg_data = beg_system_path + wstring( L"<SystemPath>" ).length();
            size_t range = line.find( L"</SystemPath>" ) - beg_data;
            line = line.substr( beg_data, range );

            // get file name
            size_t pos_last_backslash = line.find_last_of( L'\\' );

            if ( pos_last_backslash != wstring::npos )
            {
                line = line.substr( pos_last_backslash + 1 );

                if ( buflen <= line.length() )
                {
                    // ERROR: pName buffer is not large enough to fit the string + terminating NULL character.
                    return NULL;
                }

                wcscpy( pName, line.c_str() );
                tmp = pName;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

**EDIT:** Moreover, if you are using and/or parsing XML in other areas of your program, I strongly suggest using an XML parsing library such as [Xerces-C](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) or [libXml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answer. Here I got solution of my question.

PRIVATE WCHAR* GetNewSystemName()
{

```
    WCHAR line[756];
    WCHAR tempBuffer[100];

CComBSTR path = CurrentFolder.Path();

CComBSTR imagePath1 = L"rimageinfo.xml";


path.AppendBSTR(imagePath1);



    std::wfstream in(path);



WCHAR tmp[756]; 



in.getline(line, 756);

WCHAR* buffer;



buffer = wcswcs(line, L"<SystemPath>");
WCHAR *dest = wcsstr(buffer, L"</SystemPath>");
    int pos;
    pos = dest - buffer;
unsigned int i = 0;
if (wcswcs(buffer,L"<SystemPath>") != NULL && wcswcs(buffer,L"</SystemPath>") != NULL)
{ 
    for (; i < pos; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == ' ' && sizeof(tmp) == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[i] = buffer[i]; 

        }
    }

    tmp[i] = NULL;
    //break;
}

int j = i;

for (; j > 0; j--)
{
    if (tmp[j] == '\\')
    {

        break;
    }
}

j++;    
int k = 0;
for (; j < i ; j++)
{
    System_Name[k] = tmp[j];
    k++;
}

System_Name[k] = NULL;
   return System_Name;
```